# Non-isolated power electronic circuit with CLC network

Tags: power-electronics

I have some problems with a bidirectional DC-DC converter power electronics circuit. While I expect this circuit to operate at 200W under normal conditions, I am dealing with extremely high current on the input side and excessively fluctuating and unstable voltage on the output side.

I defined the switching frequency value as 300kHz and I was expecting to see an input voltage of 100V and a value of 200V at the output. As can be seen in the circuit, while the two MOSFETs on the input side are active, the MOSFETs on the output side (on the right side of the CLC network circuit) are used as rectifier diodes and are completely off. The implementation of the system is taken as an example from an IEEE article, and the values are as stated in the IEEE journal article. There is something missing or done incorrectly in the circuit, but I don't know what it is.

This is the circuit:

[image: Implemented Circuit]

This is the output voltage and current:

[image: Output Side]

This is the input voltage and current:

[image: Input Side]

Comment: I doubt L1 (presumably representing the parasitic inductance of the supply) is supposed to connect to the switching node of the left side half bridge. It’s supposed to connect to the drain of the high side FET. Please link the ”article” you refer to.

Comment: Hi jms, First of all, thank you for your interest and reply. The name of the article I referenced ”Analysis and Design of a Nonisolated Bidirectional DC–DC Converter Based on CLC Network” here is the link : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9484738

Comment: nope, i was wrong - it is supposed to connect like that. I don’t really know how that unconventional topology works, and I’m not going to spend 30€ to find out.

Comment: ok jms thank you for your interest again. By the way, if you cannot access the IEEE article, I can share the PDF of the article for you, but I do not know what the policy is regarding whether our contact information(like email etc.) is shared in this environment. I am very new to stack exchange. If it can be shared, we could even exchange ideas together to solve this system, it would be great for me, but I don't know what your opinion is.

Comment: The output FETs aren't completely off if their gate is floating. I believe HEMTs are usually depletion-mode devices, so you need to drive the gate negative (relative to source) to turn them off. If they're actually enhancement-mode devices, you just tie gate to source to turn them off. Either way, you don't leave the gate floating.

Comment: Also, HEMTs do not have body diodes like MOSFETs do, so you do need an external antiparallel diode. You have one in your circuit, so no problems there.

Comment: Hello Hearth, Actually I don't really have much experience about FETs like HEMTs but according to the circuit it is normally bidirectional and right now it is just in boost mode. I guess they are in enhancement mode and I guess so again I have to tie gate to source directly am I wrong? Also I couldn't understand your next message, all of the FETs have external diodes as you telling so I added it. However I'm a little confused whether I should change the direction of the diodes in all FETs one by one or add 1 more antiparallel diode to each of them.

Comment: Although you wrote somewhere that there is one diode has no issue, I think the problem in the circuit is in the other three.